# Flow generic of type {} is incompatible with default value of {}

Tags: flowtype

Flow reports that a default argument value of `{}` is incompatible with a generic of type `{}`.
Here is a minimal example:

```
function copy<T: {}>(o: T = {}): T {
  //                         ^ object literal [1] is incompatible with `T` [2].
  return {
    ...o
  };
}
```

The [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#object-type-) say about the type `{}`:

> Sometimes it is useful to write types that accept arbitrary objects,
>   for those you should write {}.

So in what sense are they incompatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T: {}` means "`T` is any subtype of `{}`", or in other words, `T` is an object type. If it has any required properties, `{}` is not a value of type `T`.